# Replace all the words in a string by some general variable using regex

Tags: java, regex

**Input:**

`My_PRP$ name_NN is_VBZ Anjaney_NNP Pandey_NNP I_PRP live_VBP in_IN Varanasi_NNP`

**Output :**

`#var#_PRP$#var#_NN#var#_VBZ#var#_NNP#var#_NNP#var#_PRP#var#_VBP#var#_IN#var#_NNP`

I want to replace the word before `'_'` character by `"#var#` for each sub-string in input separated by space.

I have to do it in java.

Comment: Try it first. No one is going to write the code for you.

Comment: What OS/IDE are you using? How are you reading it in? Can you post some sample code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **String#**[`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to match your pattern and do your replacements.

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?i:[a-z0-9]+_)", "#var#_")
```

Answer (score 2):

The [javadocs for the String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) reference the .replaceAll() method, which takes the regex and the replacement string as arguments.

I think that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Short of giving your full code you can do search & replace in Java like this (use `String#replaceAll`):

**Search pattern:** (using lookahead)

```
\\w+(?=_)
```

**Replacement Pattern:**

```
#var#
```

#### [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mI2kC9)

Answer (score 0):

Str.replaceAll(" [a-zA-Z0-9]+_", "#var#_")